# Play Controller throws AskTimeoutException when trying to send a request to an Akka cluster

Tags: playframework, akka-cluster

I am a beginner to Play so please bear with me.
I am trying to get my Play Controller to communicate with my backend Akka cluster.
the html get request is routed to the following method in my Controller:

```
    public CompletionStage<Result> createSession(int connectionId){
        return FutureConverters.toJava(ask(shardRegion, new CreateSessionMessage(connectionId), 2000))
                .thenApply(response -> ok((String) response));
    }
```

where

```
@Inject
    public ConnectionController(ActorSystem system) {
//other things
shardRegion = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://sharding@127.0.0.1:2551/user/connection"); 
}
```

My Akka cluster is running and I can see that the three nodes are gossiping with each other constantly.

The problem is I get the following error when createSession is called:
**play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://application/deadLetters), Path(/user/connection)]] after [2000 ms]. Message of type [com.vegaspin.actors.connection.ConnectionActorMessage$CreateSessionMessage]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.]]**

My Akka cluster is called "sharding". I am not sure why in the error message it says akka://application/deadLetters

And here is the code for creating the "connection" cluster sharding

```
    private static ActorRef setupConnectionClusterSharding(ActorSystem actorSystem) {
        ClusterShardingSettings settings = ClusterShardingSettings.create(actorSystem);
        return ClusterSharding.get(actorSystem).start(
                "connection",
                SpringExtProvider.get(actorSystem).props("ConnectionActor"),
                settings,
                ConnectionActorMessage.messageExtractor()
        );
    }
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

OK I passed this hurdle now. And I thought I might as well share it with others hopefully the answer helps someone. 
The problem was actually that I was injecting Play's ActorSystem when in fact I needed to configure my own. So here is what I did 
1. Inside Play's conf/application.config I added

```
play.akka.actor-system = "sharding"
```

which is the name of my Akka Cluster running on port 2551, 2552, and 0.
I also added the below information inside Akka block in the same application.config file.

```
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider" # offer the provider
  }

  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"] 
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1" # your host
      port = 2553 # port
    }
  }
```

As you can see I had to change the port to avoid port binding exception. I read that in one of the helpful comments in other threads.

That fixed the problem and I moved on to deal with a new problem which was an exception that was thrown in the Akka Cluster

```
[INFO] [04/27/2019 13:02:05.329] [sharding-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-23] [akka://sharding/user/connection] Message [com.actors.connection.ConnectionActorMessage$CreateSessionMessage] from Actor[akka.tcp://sharding@127.0.0.1:2553/temp/$a] to Actor[akka://sharding/user/connection] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://sharding/user/connection]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

So at least I can see now that my Play controller does send a message to the connection shard in my backend AkkaCluster. However I found out, and correct me if I am wrong, if you have your actors created inside a shard region, you should not call them from the outside using their /user/{actorType} (ex. /user/connection) but rather you should use /system/{ClusterName}/{ActorType}, (ex. /system/sharding/connection in my case)
so I changed my code from

```
public CompletionStage<Result> createSession(int connectionId){
        shardRegion = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://sharding@127.0.0.1:2551/**user**/connection");
        return FutureConverters.toJava(ask(shardRegion, new CreateSessionMessage(connectionId), 2000))
                .thenApply(response -> ok((String) response));
    }
```

to

```
public CompletionStage<Result> createSession(int connectionId){
        shardRegion = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://sharding@127.0.0.1:2551/**system/sharding**/connection");
        return FutureConverters.toJava(ask(shardRegion, new CreateSessionMessage(connectionId), 2000))
                .thenApply(response -> ok((String) response));
    }
```

Is that a correct understanding when it comes to having a Play controller call an Akka shard region in otder to create an actor?